# http.post request in Angular not reaching web api controller

Tags: angular, api, post, .net-core

I'm working on Angular 11 and having trouble in http.post request. I'm trying to send form data model to .net core API for DB processing. But for some reason the code is not reaching api controller.

Below is the code,
software-new-list-request-view.ts

```
export class SoftwareProductListRequest
{
   softwareProductListId:number;
   name:string;
   description:string;
   owner: string;
   referenceKey:string;
   softwareProductIds: number[];
}
```

software-list.component.ts

```
import { SoftwareProductListRequest } from '../../../models/software-new-list-request-view';

export class SoftwareListNewRequestComponent implements Onit {
model:SoftwareProductListRequest = new SoftwareProductListRequest();
this.softwareListService.requestNewSoftwareList(this.model)
.subscribe((result)=>{items=response;});
}
```

this.model in the above code has the form field data.

software-list-service.ts

```
requestNewSoftwareList(request) : Observable <object> {
  this.http.post<object>('https://localhost:44390/api/SoftwareList/request-new-list',requestNewList).pipe();
}
```

SoftwareListController.cs

```
[HttpPost("request-new-list")]
public object RequestNewSoftwareList(SoftwareProductListRequest request)
{
  //call DAL layer for DB save
}
```

I tried having an Observable in Angular http.post call. The code does not even hit the api controller. Any help in resolving this problem is much appreciated. I tried adding catching the error with a catch block as well, but that code is also not executed.

Thanks in advance,
Sushma

Answer (score 1):

You should return `observable` in `requestNewSoftwareList`.

```
requestNewSoftwareList(request){
  return this.http.post<object>('https://localhost:44390/api/SoftwareList/request-new-list',requestNewList);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to angular. How do I do that?```requestNewSoftwareList(request): Observable<object> {
  return this.http.post<object>('https://localhost:44390/api/SoftwareList/request-new-list',requestNewList);
}```

Comment: Try replace your `requestNewSoftwareList` method with my answer.

Comment: I don't see any change in the code you've sent. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have added `return` before `this.http.post` and removed `.pipe()`. Your original code does not return anything in `requestNewSoftwareList` and `http.post` is not subscribed by anyone. `http.post` does not send any request until it is subscribed. This is the reason your server can not see any request.

Comment: Ok thanks. I tried it and still the same problem. There's no error / exception anywhere. Still the same issue.